# What would be the easiest way to return specific bytes range from bytes32 variable?

Tags: solidity, remix

Full bytes32 var:

```
0x01000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ffffffff

function checkExpAmount(address _addr) public view returns (bytes4) {
    return players_data[_addr].playerData[28];
}
```

Getting just one byte filled with zeroes. Tried a range method [28-32] seems not possible.

[image]

The goal is to get:

```
0xffffffff
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If playersData is bytes you can use shift operator and use bytes4 to cut it

```
function checkExpAmount(address _addr) public view returns (bytes4) {
    return bytes4(players_data[_addr].playerData << 28*8);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function checkExpAmount(address _addr) public view returns (bytes4) {
    bytes1 first = players_data[_addr].playerData[28];
    bytes1 second = players_data[_addr].playerData[29];
    bytes1 third = players_data[_addr].playerData[30];
    bytes1 fourth = players_data[_addr].playerData[31];
    return bytes4(abi.encodePacked(first, second, third, fourth));
}
```